# Update app on App Store: Ionic Pro Package

Tags: ionic-framework, app-store

I read this on the Ionic Package Support Center

> Yes, you will need a Mac computer to publish an iOS app to the App Store. While you can use our Package service to build and download the native IPA file, a Mac is still required to submit the app to the App Store.

My question is do I need a Mac if I want to publish updates to the app after it has been submitted to the App Store.

Answer (score 0):

Updates to your apps will be following the same flow as original app publishing, so yes you have to use mac for publishing updates.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the live update feature that Ionic uses allows you to bypass the App Store once it has been submitted. I would recommend having a mac as a back-up for just in case purposes, but it's not absolutely necessary.This [Ionic Pro Deploy](https://ionicframework.com/pro/deploy) link explains how it works. You will need to create an account and the pro features are free to a certain extent based on how many users your app(s) have.

Comment: hey Stephen do you mean update of web-content by means of the deploy feature? I guess this can work then surely as one does't need to go through QA again, but I am not sure how Apple treats such functionality.

Comment: Well what I've personally experienced any updates or bug fixes in the back end can be automatically deployed to apps already downloaded to App Stores. So developers needing to release an app update or big fix don't have to go through the whole app store process. One thing that Ionic does not have support for currently is the build number of the app. For instance if the app version is 0.1.0. Even though it is incremented in ionic to 0.1.1, the app version won't change on the app automatically. Of course, there are hooks for this.